# Get blob contents from multiple folders using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that gets the blob contents stored in Azure container every month.
The Blobs are stored in a folder -> Eg. mycontainer/RG1/MonthlyInvoice/20200101-20200131/invoice1.csv.
I'am able to get the contents from RG1 by setting the path in 'List Blobs' trigger --> mycontainer/RG1/MonthlyInvoice/

Now, I need to get the contents in the same way but for different folders. Like -->
Eg. mycontainer/RG2/MonthlyInvoice/20200101-20200131/invoice1.csv,
mycontainer/RG3/MonthlyInvoice/20200101-20200131/invoice1.csv,
mycontainer/RG4/MonthlyInvoice/20200101-20200131/invoice1.csv

(Note: Same container is used)

Any advise regarding this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should already have all the information you need if you are using the "List Blob" action.

I'm assuming the known value that changes month to month is "20200101-20200131". I have just created a parameter for testing, but you could make this dynamic by using an expression with [utcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#utcnow)!.

Created a storage account and container with the same folder structure as you had above.

First Part of the logic app (Recurrence was set to once a month):
[image]

Second Half of the logic app:

[image]

The list blob action seems to list all the files inside of the container. I'm using the path and a conditional check to see if the path contains the date value from the parameter.

```
{
            "Id": "JTJmYWNpaW52b2ljZXMlMmZyZzIlMmZNb250aGx5SW52b2ljZSUyZjIwMjAwMTAxLTIwMjAwMTMxJTJmaW52b2ljZTEuY3N2",
            "Name": "invoice1.csv",
            "DisplayName": "invoice1.csv",
            "Path": "/aciinvoices/rg2/MonthlyInvoice/20200101-20200131/invoice1.csv",
            "LastModified": "2020-11-05T19:03:07Z",
            "Size": 12,
            "MediaType": "text/csv",
            "IsFolder": false,
            "ETag": "\"0x8D881BD6E90C327\"",
            "FileLocator": "JTJmYWNpaW52b2ljZXMlMmZyZzIlMmZNb250aGx5SW52b2ljZSUyZjIwMjAwMTAxLTIwMjAwMTMxJTJmaW52b2ljZTEuY3N2",
            "LastModifiedBy": null
        }
```

[image]

Here is the parameter I used in the testing.

[image]

I have made a few assumptions here so please if you can give more detail that would be helpful. This should help you get started at least.

Comment: Thanks John! I'll try this out and test it. Thanks so much for your response!